# Почему не срабатывает removeClass() JQ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Кнопка меню вызывает меню. Нужно что бы при клике на пункт меню, меню пряталось. Вроде всё просто, но почему то активный класс не удаляется. 
Консоль никаких ошибок не выдаёт.

```js
 $('.menu a').click(function(e){
        // e.preventDefault();
        $('.menu').removeClass('active');
    });

    $('.menu-block').click(function(){
        $('.menu').addClass('active');
    });
```

```css
.menu-block {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-block span {
  cursor: pointer; 
  display: block; 
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu {
  opacity: 0; 
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-block">
  <span class="open-menu">Открыть меню</span>
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Пункт 1</a>
    <a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
    <a href="#">Пункт 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас сначала срабатывает клик по ссылке, который удаляет класс, а потом, клик по `menu-block`, т.к. ссылки находятся внутри его, который добавляет класс `active` снова, скорее всего вам нужно открывать меню при клике на `open-menu`, а не  `menu-block`, тогда проблемы не будет. Либо воспользоваться способом из ответа ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно вызвать `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` вместо `e.preventDefault()`:

```js
 $('.menu a').click(function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $('.menu').removeClass('active');
    });

    $('.menu-block').click(function(){
        $('.menu').addClass('active');
    });
```

```css
.menu-block {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-block span {
  cursor: pointer; 
  display: block; 
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu {
  opacity: 0; 
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-block">
  <span class="open-menu">Открыть меню</span>
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Пункт 1</a>
    <a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
    <a href="#">Пункт 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Это связано с тем, что когда событие всплывает, click срабатывает также и на `.menu-block`, что ведёт к появлению класса `active` на `.menu` снова. Подробнее об этом можно почитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling).

Comment: Так и думал, что дело во всплытии. Вообще странно, я повесил нужные якоря на ссылки и теперь всё работает. Без preventDefault() разумеется.